# How to make a floating app using BASIC4Android

Tags: basic4android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an app that floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069635/how-to-make-an-app-that-floats)

Is it possible to make apps that float in front of other apps (like the mini apps on Samsung's Galaxy tab) using BASIC4Android? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a an activity with a transparent background. See this [link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/9360-render-activity-view-semi-transparent.html#post51772).

Comment: Would it achieve a result like the one shown in the URL below? The task manager is in a small window which can be moved around on top of the main screen and it has its own close button.

http://www6.pcmag.com/media/images/266078-task-manager.jpg

Comment: No. It will just have a transparent background. I don't think that it is currently possible to create a smaller activity.

Comment: Would this have anything to do with it?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme_windowIsFloating